# How to count a char only when there's a consecutive serie of it in a string via a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this regex detecting if multiple semicolons exist in a string

```
const scMatchesLength = v.match(/[;]+/)?.[0].length;
```

With such as regex , even spread semicolons are counted such as in this random string :

```
123 "321"####(x)##;654 "654" "456"####(-)##, ;"
```

the result will be `scMatchesLength = 1` for it.

But what I need to detect aren't spread semicolons. I need exactly the count of semicolons only when there's a unique serie of consecutive semicolons such as `";;;"` or `";;;;"`

It could be a better regex if the condition of having doubles quotes before and after the serie will be added to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you need is `;{2,}`

The braces indicate a quantifier and this expression asks for *two or more* of what precedes the braces, i.e. two or more semicolons.

Example:

```js
str1 = '123 "321"####(x)##;654 "654" "456"####(-)##, ;"';
str2 = '123 "321"####(x)##;;654 "654" "456"####(-)##, ;"';

console.log(test(str1));
console.log(test(str2));

function test(str) {
   return str.match(/;{2,}/)?.[0].length;
}
```